# vuejs sort by year and find by tag in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js

Building a project in VueJS with data coming from an api (using axios):
I have a list of projects with props (year, location, etc) and tags (house, park, etc). 
I have made this filter to toggle the sort by prop:

```
sortby(data) {
 // data = {prop: "year", tag: "house"}
 //
 if (data.prop === "year") {
   this.projects.sort((a, b) => (a[data.prop] < b[data.prop] ? 1 : -1));
 } else {
   this.projects.sort((a, b) => (a[data.prop] < b[data.prop] ? -1 : 1));
 }
},
```

but after the sort I would like to only show the objects that have `tag === "house"`.

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: `.filter(({tag}) => tag === 'house')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript array filter

```js
const filteredProjects = projects.filter(({tag}) => tag === "house");
```

or put it on the computed properties

```js
data: () => ({
  projects: [
    {prop: "year", tag: "house"},
    ...
  ]
}),
computed: {
    filteredProjects: function () {
      return this.projects.filter(({tag}) => tag === "house");
    }
  }
```

and then use it in your template

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ filteredProjects }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `projects.filter( ({tag}) => tag === "house")` thats shorter syntax

Comment: thanks for the help! i have some errors, but i guess im doing something wrong. i'll prepare a jsfiddle